# return con mensaje no está funcionando laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo una función donde tengo que actualizar la página y devolver un mensaje, todo funciona correctamente, sin embargo no aparece ningún mensaje, con otras funciones eso no ocurre

mi función

```
public function startStop($id){

        $this->meoRepository->startStopMeo($id);

        if (MeoState::NOT_SENDING_REPORT){
            return redirect()->route('digest-report.index')
                ->with(["message" => 'test']);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('digest-report.index')
                ->with(["message" => 'test2']);
        }
    }
```

se supone que debería mostrarme los mensajes "test" o "test2" pero no muestra nada, (cabe destacar que ya estoy en index cuando ejecuto la función de redireccionar nuevamente a index), funciona todo correctamente, hice debug y todo lo que necesito hacer lo hace, pero no me muestra ningún mensaje de confirmación

nota: el if funciona bien, está entrando correctamente a la clase y tomando su valor

con otras funciones funciona correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo le estás indicando que muestre el mensaje?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ en los return redirect with message, con las otras funciones está todo correcto

Comment: deberias adjuntar el codigo donde intentas mostrar el mensaje

Comment: @JoelMuñozMoran no es un correo, quiero mostrar un mensaje, como si fuera una notificación

Comment: deberias adjuntar el codigo donde intentas mostrar el mensaje

Comment: @JoelMuñozMoran es el que está adjuntado, el message que aparece ahí

Comment: No, adjunta el view donde intentas mostrar el mensaje

Comment: Como tú mismo dices,  "con otras funciones funciona correctamente". Por lo que el problema está en otro lugar que no estás mostrando en la pregunta, y no es algo que es algo que podamos reproducir para responderte. Necesitamos más información. Dale una leída a la documentación si te interesa entender lo que estás haciendo [Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) y [Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#flash-data).

Answer (score 0):

De la manera en lo que yo implemente ese tipo de funciones es la siguiente:

```
return redirect(route('index'))->with('status', 'Operación exitosa');
```

Y en mi `blade` (uso PUG), en donde redirijo, tengo una condición creada de esta manera:

```
@if(session('status'))
.errorContainer
    p {{ session('status') }}
@endif
```

Cuando redirige, crea una variable de sesión válida solo para la siguiente petición, la vista detecta su existencia y aparece el mensaje, una vez recargada la página, el mensaje desaparece